# How to remove JTabbedPane border?

Tags: java, swing, border, jtabbedpane

I want to remove the awkward blue border which I cannot remove by doing `myTabbedPane.setBorder(null);`. What is a way of doing that?

This is the blue border I am talking about:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlAh5.png]

As I am new to the swing java library, I would also like to know how all the properties of components are changed if there is no method/it doesn't work. I heard there is something called UIManager but I can't find useful information about it.

The only thing I tried was calling setBorder property and calling null on it.

Comment: *I would also like to know how all the properties of components are changed if there is no method/it doesn't work.* - then you need to create a custom UI class for that component and do the custom painting yourself. Generally not a good idea. *I heard there is something called UIManager* - each LAF has some properties defined for the component that can be changed. See: [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/). You can also search this site using "jtabbedpane border" for other postings on this topic.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These properties are defined by the Look & Feel you are using (e.g. Windows L&F or Metal L&F).

You can change these properties globally (i.e. this applies to all JTabbedPanes you are using). The following code works for the Windows L&F and the Motiv L&F (you need to check for other L&F implementations):

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Main());
    }

    public Main() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JTabbedPane pane = new JTabbedPane();
        pane.addTab("A", new JPanel());
        pane.addTab("B", new JPanel());
        pane.addTab("C", new JPanel());

        Insets insets = UIManager.getInsets("TabbedPane.contentBorderInsets");
        insets.top = -1;
        insets.bottom = -1;
        insets.left = -1;
        insets.right = -1;
        UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentBorderInsets", insets);

        this.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800, 600);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```